# What is the meaning of ～ないでいると～

Tags: grammar, translation

The original sentence is:

> 俺が呆れてものを言えないでいると、ハルヒはディジタルカメラを手にして、記念に写真を撮っておこうと言い出した。

I don't think the で in ～ない*で*いると～ indicates て形 but rather I have the feeling that ～ないでいると～ shows two situations that almost occur at the same time.

I would translate the above sentence as:

> While still in daze that I could not say/reply anything, Haruhi took a digital camera and said 'Let's take some photos as souvenirs'

or literally as:

> While I was in a situation where I could not express my astonishment, (before I could do anything), Haruhi took a digital camera and said "Let's tale some photos as souvenirs."

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the chapter and page number of the source?

Comment: @akj Sure, it's 涼宮ハルヒの憂鬱・谷川 流・角川スニーカー文庫、第四章・１２９頁・(右から)6欄。

Comment: The part "While I was in a situation where ~~" is excellent and so is the part "before I could do anything".

Comment: @l'électeur Thank you for confirming that I understood, at least partially, the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

ないで is the casual version of ず(に), which is similar to the なくて form, but instead of meaning "didn't do (verb), and...," it means "without doing (verb), ...."

> 何も言わずに走った。
>   何も言わず、走った。
>   何も言わないで走った。
>   Ran without saying anything.

As opposed to:

> 何も言わなくて走った。
>   Didn't say anything and ran.

Of course the いると part makes it more complicated to translate, as I don't think "without" fits in naturally. I think you basically got it, but here's my try:

> 俺が呆れてものを言えないでいると…
>   While I was still shocked and unable to speak...

[Tae Kim's explanation of ないで and ず(に)](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/negativeverbs2)

Comment: OP's TL appears to capture the nuance of the original more accurately than yours.  I do not see the continuity of the situation expressed in yours.  「～～ないでいる」 always means that the situation where ~~ is not happening lasts a while.  It lasts long enough for another action to take place.

Comment: Yeah, I get that sense that the situation persists for a while due to いる, but I'm having trouble phrasing naturally in English. I thought "while" would convey that, but I'll add "still" in as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer, nevertheless, what throw me a bit off here is not really ないで but more the combination with いると and the fact that 呆れても is before のを (That's why I said `...where I could not express my astonishment...` but I am not sure if it is the right interpretation). But my question may not be very clear about that.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted that as being 飽きれて and 物を言えないでいる, so "shocked" and "without being able to say a thing." The と essentially means "when."

Comment: @変幻出没 Might you have mistakenly parsed the sentence as 「俺が呆れても、のを言えないでいると」 instead of 「俺が呆れて、物を言えないでいると」? That might attribute to your confusion. 「物を言う」 is an expression itself: http://jisho.org/word/%E7%89%A9%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86

Comment: @akj Thank you a lot, you solved my last problem on this sentence.